# Using GridRecorder . TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'save_root'

Tags: python

I am trying to run this code but I can't get past this error.

Please point out what's going wrong here and link some docs/articles if possible.

```
from marlgrid.utils.video import GridRecorder
import gym_minigrid

env = gym_minigrid.envs.empty.EmptyEnv(size=10)
env.max_steps = 200

env = GridRecorder(env, render_kwargs={"tile_size": 11})

obs = env.reset()
env.recording = True

count = 0
done = False

while not done:
    act = env.action_space.sample()
    obs, rew, done, _ = env.step(act)
    count += 1

env.export_video("test_minigrid.mp4")
```

Error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gym_minigrid-1.0.2-py3.8.egg/gym_minigrid/roomgrid.py:302: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if front_cell is None or front_cell.type is 'wall':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    env = GridRecorder(env, render_kwargs={"tile_size": 11})
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'save_root'
```

Comment: the constructor called on line 7 `GridRecorder` requires additional arguments. You will need to look at the documentation for the library you are using - or you can load this library into a Python REPL and run `help(GridRecorder)` and that may show you how to use the constructor.

Comment: @nlloyd sorry but I am completely blank here. I absolutely don't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the error message:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'save_root'
```

Just add `save_root` as one more argument to it.

Like this: `env = GridRecorder(env,"save_root", render_kwargs={"tile_size": 11})`
and it will start working.
Be sure to install `moviepy` and `PYOPENGL`.

Following is the `requirements.txt` file.

```
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
cloudpickle==1.6.0
decorator==4.4.2
ez-setup==0.9
gym==0.18.3
gym-minigrid==1.0.2
idna==2.10
imageio==2.9.0
imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.4
llvmlite==0.36.0
marlgrid==0.0.5
moviepy==1.0.3
numba==0.53.1
numpy==1.20.3
Pillow==8.2.0
proglog==0.1.9
pyglet==1.5.15
PyOpenGL==3.1.5
PyOpenGL-accelerate==3.1.5
requests==2.25.1
scipy==1.6.3
tqdm==4.60.0
urllib3==1.26.4
```

Use `Python 3.9.5` as the interpreter in VS-Code. It doesn't work with `Python 3.8.5` it guess.